# Laravel updating multiple related models

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update multiple models at once, I didn't tried any function so far, but I would not if there is no way of doing it.
For example, I have model Products and there is few relations, with another relations inside.
And I'm getting it like this:

```
Products::where('id', $id)->with('category', 'info.country', 'images', 'packages.package.info.country')->firstOrFail()
```

So is there any way to make update function at once? For example

```
Products::where('id', $id)->with('category', 'info.country', 'images', 'packages.package.info.country')->firstOrCreate($request);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What are you trying to update exactly?

Comment: Basically every model, that \is connected to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update multiple models with a single statement as you can't update multiple tables in one SQL statement. However, you can use a transaction to make sure that all statements are treated atomically.

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->category()->update([
        'name' => 'Category 1',
    ]);
    // rest of the statements

    DB::commit();
    // all good
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // something went wrong
}
```

Comment: update..join queries are totally valid and can be written in eloquent

Comment: Yeah, I never said otherwise @maaarghk :) But the point is you can't update multiple tables in one statement, and since it's not using the eager loaded relations to filter the query or anything, they are pretty useless in this case. BTW, eager loading relationships doesn't always result in a join: i.e: if the related model does not have a foreign key to the primary model, Laravel will use a separate query to retrieve the related data.